# Combining float and nth-child clear behavior and dynamic hide box

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

I gonna try to make a list of element float and clear both at the next new row because height of box are unknown and we can hide box to highlight box by category, like:

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var show = $(this).data('show');
    if(show == 'all') {
        $('div').show();
    } else {
        $('div').hide();
        $('.' + show).show();
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
article {
    width: 400px;
}
div {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.category-b {
    background-color: #eee;
}
div:nth-child(4n+5) {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a data-show="all" href="#">All</a> /
    <a data-show="category-a" href="#">Category A</a> /
    <a data-show="category-b" href="#">Category B</a>
</nav>
<article>
    <div class="category-b">hello</div>
    <div class="category-a">hello world folk</div>
    <div class="category-a">lorem ipsum dolores</div>
    <div class="category-a">bonjour Mr</div>
    <div class="category-b">Katarina vs Alistar</div>
    <div class="category-a">hello</div>
    <div class="category-a">hello world folk</div>
    <div class="category-b">lorem ipsum dolores</div>
    <div class="category-b">bonjour Mr</div>
    <div class="category-a">Katarina vs Alistar</div>
    <div class="category-b">hello</div>
    <div class="category-b">hello world folk</div>
    <div class="category-b">lorem ipsum dolores</div>
    <div class="category-a">bonjour Mr</div>
    <div class="category-a">Katarina vs Alistar</div>
    <div class="category-a">hello</div>
    <div class="category-b">hello world folk</div>
    <div class="category-b">lorem ipsum dolores</div>
    <div class="category-a">bonjour Mr</div>
    <div class="category-b">Katarina vs Alistar</div>
</article>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/Lwyte7sm/

The problem are, when you select an category the nth-child also takes into account the hidden box by display:none and broke the mosaic.
Would anyone have a solution? Css solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest CSS solution:

Set a fixed height for each DIV, then float left without clear:both.

```
div { height:80px; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/Lwyte7sm/1/)

Or, you can use jquery to get the highest height for all DIVs and float left to get the same result.

/*====================================================*/

How about use display:inline-block; instead of float:left; ?

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/Lwyte7sm/3/)**

*The width % might need to decrease as display:inline-block; generates some space between the DIVs.

Comment: I dont want to fixed height of box because content can be different and fit, i used px to width but in fact it used % to responsive